# Verify the order of a dynamic web table after it has been changed

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm writing automation testing script on a website using selenium web driver. I need to verify the order of a dynamic web table after the order has been changed. So far i have written the code to put all the elements into a list for each rows and columns. After I click on change order of the row on the website, how do I verify that the correct order is displayed?

e.g. If I move the first row down so it becomes the second row and the second row becomes the first, I need to verify that they have been swapped.

Here's the html code for the web table.

```
<table class="favTable">
  <caption><h2 class="hideCaption">My Favorite Reports</h2></caption>
<tbody>
  <tr class="headerRow">
    <th scope="col" class="colCO">Change Order</th>
    <th scope="col" class="colFN">Favorite Name</th>
    <th scope="col" class="colRF">Remove Favorite</th>
    <th scope="col" class="colEFN">Edit Favorite Name</th>
   </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td class="colCO">
      <a href="#" onclick="return UpSort(this);">
        <img alt="Increase Order" src="Resources/Images/up_sort.png">
       </a>
      <a href="#" onclick="return DownSort(this);">
        <img alt="Decrease Order" src="Resources/Images/down_sort.png">
       </a>
     </td>
    <td class="colFN editableCell">
      <a id="150219030000EditLink" href="/app/FDR2019/FormularySearch.aspx?PI=150219030000">CY 2019 Search Formulary
      </a>
       <label for="150219030000EditBox" class="HiddenText" style="display:none;">CY 2019 Search Formulary Favorite Name</label><input id="150219030000EditBox" class="favNameEditBox" style="display:none;" maxlength="50" type="text" value="">
       <input id="150219030000SaveNameBtn" style="display:none;" type="button" value="Save" onclick="return SaveFavoriteTitle(this, '150219030000');">
       <input id="150219030000CancelNameBtn" class="favTitleCancelBtn" style="display:none;" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="return CancelEditFavorites(this);">
     </td>
    <td class="colRF">
      <a href="#" onclick="return RemoveFavorite(this, '150219030000');">
        <img alt="Remove From Favorites" src="Resources/Images/remove.png">
        </a>
      </td>
    <td class="colEFN">
      <a href="#" onclick="return EditFavorites(this, '150219030000', 'true');">
      <img alt="Edit Favorite Name" src="Resources/Images/edit.png">
      </a>
     </td>
    <td style="display:none">
      <span class="pageIDCol">150219030000</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
```

This is the code i have written to put the values into two lists.

```
@Keyword

public getWebTable(){

  WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();

  WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody"));

  List <WebElement> rowsTable = table.findElements(By.tagName('tr'));

  int rowsCount = rowsTable.size();

  System.out.println('Number of rows in the table are ' + rowsCount);

  for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {

    List <WebElement> rowColumns = rowsTable.get(i).findElements(By.tagName('td'));

    int colsCount = rowColumns.size();

    System.out.println((('Number of columns in row number ' + i) + ' are ') + colsCount);

    for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++) {

      String content = rowColumns.get(j).getText();

      System.out.println((((('Element text in row number ' + i) + ' and column number ') + j) + ' is ') + content);

    }

  }

}
```

This is the picture of the web table on the site. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[picture of web table with increase and decrease order button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ulvz.png)

Comment: So when you click change order, it randomly changes the order? What does it sort the table on? Also, how are you moving down and up between rows? Dragging and dropping or clicking up and down buttons?

Comment: There are two buttons for each row that allows you to move the current row up or down. It doesn't sort the table in any way but the way you want it to. I will include the snapshot of the table and its html. thanks!

Comment: So, if you want to move Data Entry 2018 up or down, then first you need to get its text. And then when you move it up verify that the text is shown in the first row or third if you moved it down.

Comment: I am getting the texts when I iterate through the columns in each row in the second for loop. How do I verify that the text has moved down if I clicked down.. sorry I am new with selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

You can check direct `indexOf()` an `WebElement` in `List<WebElement>` or check the text value's index like this:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("someId")); // dummy locator
List<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
for (WebElement element: elements) {
    texts.add(element.getText());
}
int positionOfFoo1Text = texts.indexOf("Foo1") + 1; // indexed from 0
int positionOfFoo2Text = texts.indexOf("Foo2") + 1;

// clear texts before changing DOM
texts.clear();
```